# Use Rails 6 I18n translations for custom/user-specific naming schemas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

What I would like to do is utilize the I18n localization structure to handle organziation-specific naming schemas, independently of the users actual local. Something like:

**Default Naming Schema**

*show.en.yml*

```
en:
  show:
    title: Component
```

**Organization A Nameing Schema**

*show.org_a.yml*

```
org_a:
  show:
    title: Widget
```

**Organization B Nameing Schema**

*show.org_b.yml*

```
org_b:
  show:
    title: Sprocket
```

I've tried to just set a custom local using `I18n.locale = organziation.slug.to_sym || I18n.default_locale` (where `slug` would be `org_a`, `org_b`, etc.), but that just yields a `:org_a is not a valid locale` error. Unfortunately, searching for possible solutions has not been all that fruitful.

Is there a way to add custom locals, or should I be approaching this problem a different way (using `Rails 6`)?

Comment: I think creating a [custom i18n backend](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/rails-i18n-3-quick-tips-and-1-crazy-abuse/#sharing-partials-between-object-types) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Rails 4.2 (since that is what I have easy access to right now) to allow for custom locales but it should work for Rails 6 as well (or something similar to this):

```
I18n.available_locales = I18n.available_locales + [:org_a, :org_b]
I18n.locale            = organziation.slug.to_sym || I18n.default_locale
```

Maybe append to the available locales early on in a config file, or similar.